# Using Grep In A For Loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

`/home/errorcodes` contains:

```
421 RP-001
421 RP-002
421 RP-003
550 SC-001
550 SC-002
550 SC-003
550 SC-004
550 DY-001
550 DY-002
550 DY-001
550 OU-001
550 OU-002
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Elogs=/home/elogs.txt
Errors=/home/errorcodes
for i in `cat $Errors`; do
    #Get Error Logs
    grep "$i" /home/eximlog >> $Elogs
done
```

Debug:

```
+ cat /home/errorcodes
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 421 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep RP-001 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 421 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep RP-002 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 421 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep RP-003 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep SC-001 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep SC-002 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep SC-003 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep SC-004 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep DY-001 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep DY-002 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep DY-001 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep OU-001 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep 550 /home/eximlog
+ for i in '`cat $Errors`'
+ grep OU-002 /home/eximlog
```

Why does the loop read all codes like "421" and "RP-001" separately? And bring duplicate result. Grep should consider codes a single string like: `"421 RP-001"`
And debugging should be like this:

```
+ for i in 'cat $Errors'
+ grep 421 RP-001 /home/eximlog
    ︙
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell will perform *word splitting* on `$(cat $Errors)`.  That is why you get one word at a time instead of one line at a time.

You want a `while read...` loop:

```
while read -r line; do
    #Get Error Logs
    grep "$line" /home/eximlog >> $Elogs
done <"$Errors"
```

`read` is line oriented: it reads one line at a time.

Or, this may work for you and it doesn't need any looping at all:

```
 grep -f "$Errors" /home/eximlog
```

The `-f` options tells `grep` to read patterns from a file, one pattern per line.

Also, it looks to me like your error code patterns are fixed strings not regular expressions.  In that is the case, to avoid unpleasant surprises, add the `-F` option to `grep`:

```
 grep -Ff "$Errors" /home/eximlog
```

Comment: Yes  `grep -f "$Errors" /home/eximlog`  works for me. thanks @John1024

Comment: was returning only one line for me, and I discovered this is due to CRLF line endings in the source file, so make sure you have it converted to Unix EOL